# Stopping a server request

Tags: java, tomcat, request, report

I have a web app (java, tomcat) that allows users to generate reports through crystal reports. Problem is if a user requests a huge report that takes hours to complete, my whole app grinds to a halt. Is there a way to stop a request like this, say if after 5 minutes it has not been complete? Other than optimizing for speed and limiting report sizes, are there any other work-arounds?

Comment: _Why_ does your application grind to a halt?

Comment: because the report generation is hogging up the CPU and memomey resources of tomcat i think

Comment: Running reports like this on a transactional system is not a good idea - you should think about redesign...

Comment: @ha1ogen you may want to investigate that using both the native Windows tools and e.g. jvisualvm in the JDK.  This will allow you to see exactly what goes wrong instead of guessing (which humans are notoriously bad at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not running your report generation in another Thread. It is better to run the report generation in another Thread and send a link back to user when it is ready.

You can use ExecutorService of java and set some timeout for the thread and it will expire if it takes more than the time you have allocated for it.

Search for Java ExecutorService, Future, Callable tutorial

Sample code:

```
 Callable<Integer> callable = new CallableImpl(2);
  ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
  Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callable);
  Integer result = future.get(600,TimeUnit.seconds));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to run report generation in a separate thread (or maybe using `ExecutorService`) and call `Thread.interrupt()` when generation time exceeds some threshold. Chances are the thread will be interrupted if it currently blocks on I/O (network, database).